# Toad/Oracle: Which role do I need to see all Tablespaces?

Tags: database, oracle11g, roles, toad

I am currently trying to setup a new schema on an Oracle 11g RAC. I received a user and a corresponding schema and have full rights within my schema.

My problem is that I only see the system tablespaces (system, sysaux, users, temp, undotbs). I have already setup other schematas on this database and I know that there is another tablespace called data. On this tablespsace reside all our tables and so should the new tables that I want to create.

The other users I used so far had admin privileges so I had no problems, the new one is just a "simple" user, but received the "SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE" so I should be able to see sessions and at least should be able to kill my own sessions.

Anyone knows which role I need to see the data schema and create tables on it?

Best regards,
CB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grant the `UNLIMITED TABLESPACE` privilege to the user, which permits a user to use an unlimited amount of any tablespace in the database.

Comment: Hello mavroprovato, thanks for reply. My problem is that I don't see any tablespace other than the system ones and because of this I can't use them.

Best regards, CB

Comment: If you have granted the UNLIMITED TABLESPACE privilege to the user, then you are not seeing the tablespaces because there aren't any

Comment: I asked my collegues and it seems that most of the data was transferred to another database and the remaining few tables and stuff have been moved to the users tablespace and the data tablespace has been removed about a week ago. Communication is a great thing, when it's done :) Thank you for your support.